# Creating a new pandas dataframe through a complex transpose or sub-setting operation

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to use pandas to transform an existing dataframe into a different format for plotting. The data frame structure right now is below:

```
       OTU1      OTU2  OTU3  OTU4  \
S1   0.000055  0.000000     0.000110        0.003354   
S2  0.000230  0.000128     0.000653        0.007691   
S3  0.000083  0.000190     0.000444        0.002236   
S4  0.000346  0.000097     0.000614        0.010036   
S5  0.000000  0.000152     0.000157        0.001477   

              OTU5  OTU6     OTU7     OTU8  \
S1        0.000766       0.001661  0.000255  0.000665   
S2       0.001636       0.001308  0.001027  0.009478   
S3       0.000381       0.001251  0.000416  0.000544   
S4       0.002098       0.000816  0.000296  0.000723   
S5       0.000276       0.001153  0.000150  0.001517   

        OTU9        sum  Latitude  Longitude  \
S1   0.006252   2.391780  -42.3640   -44.0318   
S2  0.016170  66.947991  -39.9648   -42.4232  
S3  0.001989  60.255512  -35.0093   -39.4310  
S4  0.015191  60.941558  -44.7117   -45.5265 
S5  0.001467  15.296117   37.5673   -50.6855 

                              Depth  
S1      50.0  
S2    149.0  
S3    151.0  
S4    149.0  
S5    103.0
```

What I would like to do is transform this in such a way that it looks like this where I am generating new rows based on existing columns, so in this example I'd create 9 new rows for S1, one row for each OTU group:

```
   group  value    Latitude  Longitude  Depth
S1 OTU1 0.000055 -42.3640   -44.0318 50.0
S2 OTU1 0.000230 -39.9648   -42.4232 149.0
S3 OTU1 0.000083  -35.0093   -39.4310 151
....
```

I'm still learning pandas and plotting stuff so suggestions on how to do this are much appreciated.

*UPDATE*

I did come up with a solution and put it below in the answers but am open to other suggestions if people have another idea.

Comment: Sorry I guess transposition may have been the wrong word to use there. In theory yes I'd be taking a subset of the columns and generating a bunch of new rows based on that so I'd have 9 rows for the S1 sample and 9 rows for the S2 each row representing a unique group.

Comment: What are you trying to plot?

Comment: Thats actually related to another post I had made earlier today (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67961562/plotting-coordinates-on-a-map-with-pie-charts-instead-of-normal-markers) about trying to plot pie charts on a global map. I have been stumped on a way to do it in python but I found this example which does what I want but in R but I'd need to get my data in the same format they have and its a large dataset so I am trying not to have to do it manually: https://jethroemmanuel.netlify.app/2018/05/30/plot-pie-chart-tuna-landed-catch-map-in-r/

Comment: can you provide the source code instead : ``df.to_dict('records')``

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out a way to solve this myself, heres the solution I came up with:

```
empty_df=pd.DataFrame()
columns_=["OTU1","OTU2","OTU3","OTU4","OTU5","OTU6","OTU7","OTU8","OTU9"]
for f in columns_:
    tmp_df=df3[[f, 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Depth']]
    tmp_df["group"]=f
    tmp_df=tmp_df.rename(columns={f: "value"})
    empty_df=pd.concat([empty_df,tmp_df])
print(empty_df)
```